# Sorting issue with CListCtrl::InsertItem()

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I am using VS2015 to develop and need insert items into a CListCtrl object. I use InsertItem() to add the new item at the end of the list. Below is my code

```
int nIdx = m_SessionTimesListCtrl.InsertItem(
            m_SessionTimesListCtrl.GetItemCount(), IFMT("%s/%s/%s", getTime(), getWeekDay(), getTimeZone()));
```

My intention is to get below list

03:00:00/MON/US

17:00:00/TUS/US

17:00:00/WED/US

17:00:00/THU/US

however, I got this list

03:00:00/MON/US

17:00:00/THU/US

17:00:00/TUS/US

17:00:00/WED/US

the only explain is CListCtrl sorts the inputs despites I give it the index to be inserted.

I checked my resource file and there is no sorting attribute been used.

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST_SESSION_TIMES,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,7,7,152,58
```

So, my question is how I can disable the auto sorting of CListCtrl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LVS_REPORT` style is normally used when there is a need to display the items in a sortable fashion. Using this style may result in the list control having a [`CHeaderCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sdtw025.aspx%20CHeaderCtrl) upon which one could click to sort the list items.

If sorting is not desired, and if there's no need to display a column header, you might want to not use the `LVS_REPORT` style. Choose something like `LVS_LIST` style instead.

If a column header is desired, but no sorting is required, you might want to disable the sorting properties of the control by doing something like:

```
m_SessionTimesListCtrl.ModifyStyle(LVS_SORTASCENDING|LVS_SORTDESCENDING, 0);
```